# Language parser for R

Tags: r, parsing, nlp

Is there a parser in R to process natural language strings and convert them into R instructions? Something like LEX and BISON for C++. For example it would turn this string:

```
Dataset: Cars - Column: Speed: 15 - Range: [20-40]
```

into

```
filter_cars <- cars[cars$speed <= 15,][20:40,]
```

What I've seen works only for integrating R expressions in C++, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the functions evaluate() and parse(). parse() converts a string into an expression. evaluate() can handle expressions:

```
data(mtcars)
cars <- mtcars # example data

expr <- "filter_cars <- cars[cars$speed <= 15,][20:40,]" # text string
eval(parse(text = expr)) # convert string to expression and evaluate
```

EDIT: If you want to create the expressions automatically you will have to write your own function. paste() or cat() are useful for creating text strings from multiple inputs.

Comment: I know eval and parse. But what I'm looking for is a tool or library that lets me analyze the first string and translate it into the second one so that then I can use eval and parse.

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of a R package that does this. You may have to write your own function do that.